# codeigniter admin panel file structure

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, session, authentication

I am having difficulty setting up a admin section with a codeigniter.

I have just added a new folder in controller folder called fam_Admin.

So structure is like following:

-controllers 
  --->fam_admin 
     ---->-login.php

in routes.php I added the following code:
         `$route['fam_admin'] = "fam_admin/login";`

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {
  public function index() {
    //$login['main_content'] = '/fam_admin/login';
    //$this -> load -> view('fam_admin/includes/template', $login);
    $this -> load -> view('fam_admin/login');
  }
  public function validate_login() {
    $username = $this -> input -> post('username');
    $password = $this -> input -> post('password');
    $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|callback_credential_check');
    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
      $this -> load -> view('fam_admin/login');
    }
  }
  public function credential_check() {
    //Field validation succeeded.&nbsp; Validate against database
    $username = $this -> input -> post('username');
    $password = $this -> input -> post('password');
    $this -> load -> model('fam_admin/admin');
    //query the database
    $query = $this -> admin -> check_login($username, $password);
    if (!$query) {
      $this -> form_validation -> set_message('login_check', 'Invalid username or password');
      return false;
      $this -> index();
    } else {
      $data = array(
        'username' => $this -> input -> post('username'),
        'is_logged_in' => true
      );
      $this -> session -> set_userdata($data);
      //redirect('fam_admin/main_section');
      redirect('site/logged_in');
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Above is the code for login.php but when the login credentials are validated it gives following error in google chrome. You can try it by entering false credentials and it should give you errors and load the same login form.

The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/index.php/fam_admin/login/validate_login. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have a controller called "main_section" at `fam_admin/main_section.php`? I don't see anything in your code that suggests "main_section" should load anything at all. You even commented out the redirect to it, are you sure you're giving us the right details? Also have you turned on error reporting and display_errors?

Comment: I have edited the code now. I was trying out something and therefore there was a error in the posted code.

Comment: Do you mean error reporting in php.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, this is an issue:

```
if ( ! $query) {
    // ...
    return false;
    $this -> index();
}
```

Once you `return` something, that's it - the rest of the code won't run - so the `index` method doesn't get called and there is no output at all.

...but, you shouldn't be loading views in a function that's supposed to just handle data validation.

I would rearrange things a bit, try simplifying your controller to this:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->model('fam_admin/admin');
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $query = $this->admin->check_login($username, $password);
            if ($query)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('site/logged_in');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('login_check', 'Invalid username or password');
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('fam_admin/login');
    }

}
```

Comment: tried above it didn't work, I then turned the errors on and the error was with the MD5 function in my model. The above did clean up y code and will help me in future.

Comment: Yeah even without that error you would have had another one. Yes sorry to not be clear before, you want these settings while developing: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` Turn `display_errors` off when you go live and turn the error reporting down to an appropriate level for logging.